# SELECT rows from SQLite Database where condition met with limit return rows with smallest IDs

Tags: sqlite

I have a database with an PRIMARY KEY INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT column named `id` and a condition flag column, call it `condition` which is an INTEGER. 
I would like to be able to SELECT a given number of rows `N` where `conditon=1`. That is easy enough to query (for example if `N=10`):

```
SELECT data FROM table_name WHERE condition=1 LIMIT 10;
```

However I would like to be guaranteed that the rows I receive are also those rows with the smallest values of `id` from the full set of rows where `condition=1`. For example if rows with `id` between 1 and 20 have `condition=1` I would like my query to be guaranteed to return rows with `id=1 - 10`.

My understanding is that `ORDER BY` is completed after the query so I don't think including `ORDER BY id` would make this a guarantee. Is there a way to guarantee this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are wrong:

```
SELECT data FROM table_name WHERE condition=1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 10;
```

is what you need.  
It will sort the rows you need and then the limit is applied.  
From http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-limit/

> SQLite LIMIT and ORDER BY clause 
>  
>   We typically use the LIMIT clause with ORDER BY clause, because we are 
>   interested in getting the numberof rows in a specified order, not in 
>   unspecified order. 
>   The ORDER BY clause appears before the LIMIT clause in the SELECT
>   statement. 
>   SQLite sorts the result set **before** getting the number of
>   rows specified in the LIMIT clause.

Comment: Could you point to a place in the documentation that verifies this claim?